# Installing Smooch using pods does not listing under dependency

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode7.3, smooch

I have just installed Smooch sdk using pods(pod 'smooch').
Installation was perfect but its not visible under pods xcoproject->Target.

I also tried  under header, but not able to import under swift project.

I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks & regards
Suraj Gupta

Comment: After installing a Pod you have to use the *workspace* file, not the project file.

Comment: I am using workspace file

Comment: as you are working with Swift, did you include  use_frameworks! to your Podfile?

Comment: Yes.
All other pods are working fine, except 'Smooch' pods.

Answer (score 1):

The Smooch framework is closed source, and is distributed as a pre-compiled framework, so it does not deserve it's own build target under the Pods project. To be able to use Smooch code in Swift, you need to import the framework in your app's [Bridging Header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) file.

```
#import <Smooch/Smooch.h>
```

Comment: Tried this.
Getting error that could not build module

Comment: Can you generate a sample project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @surajGupta Did you solve it now ? I installed it and it's working fine with the bridging error.